# Algorithm for visiting nodes only once

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Let's say I have an array of N elements. I call a recursive function somehow like this: (no specific language here, just pseudocode)

```
recursive(myArray){
    // do something awesome and provide base case etc
    // also get mySecondArray based on myArray
    for(i=0;i<mySecondArray.length;i++){
        recursive(mySecondArray[i];
    }
}
```

As you can see I need to call this function on every element of another array created inside based on some conditions and other functions called on myArray.

The problem I am having is that mySecondArray always has **some** of the elements that were already in myArray. I do not want to call recursion again on those elements.

**Q:** What would be the best algorithm approach to solve this?

If you need more info just let me know (I didn't get into details since it gets more complicated)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a *hashmap/set/dictionary/whatever-you-call-it* to look up the elements.

Python solution:

```
def recursive(myArray, mySet = None):
    if mySet is None:
        mySet = { myArray }
    else:
        mySet.add(myArray)

    for mySecondArray in myArray:
        if mySecondArray not in mySet:
            recursive(myArray, mySet)
```

By the way writing recursive functions like that is a very bad idea in general. You should use a single function and a stack of the arguments if possible.

P.S.: Your code was incomplete by the way but the idea is the same.